# How do I copy packages within a PPA from one release to another? (nonsensical "same version already has published binaries" error)

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I keep getting weird errors from launchpad when I try and copy the Maverick packages to Natty for the PPA.  I select the wine1.3 package (not in Ubuntu), select "copy to this PPA", and then select "rebuild the resulting binaries".  This error emerges:

> The following source cannot be copied:
>
> wine1.3 1.3.11-0ubuntu1 in maverick
>   (same version already has published
>   binaries in the destination archive)

I have no idea what this error means but apparently it doesn't mean there are binaries in the destination archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error because the version wasn't bumped and the version is exactly the same. You're not supposed to have the same package with the same version in the same ppa. For releasing with multiple releases I normally either bump the minor version:

```
mypackage_1.2-0ubuntu1 < for lucid
mypackage_1.2-0ubuntu2 < for maverick
```

Or I actually name them per release.

```
mypackage_1.2-0lucid2
```

There is supposed to be a more formal, debian way of doing this, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Yes, I do the "different names for different releases" thing too, but in this case I'm using the copy packages function and there is no existing natty packages at all.  If copying into "this ppa" doesn't ever work, why is it an option?

Comment: It's a bug in launchpad that it either doesn't change the name/version or that it offers the option. The result is expected from dumb code and I bet the code was designed to move packages from one ppa to another, not from one release to another.

Comment: Upon investigation, you CAN copy packages provided you don't rebuild them.  I think this is actually the same way the Ubuntu archive works -- packages that haven't changed version in 3 releases were actually built 3 releases ago and are binary-identical.  Useful for forward-porting.

Comment: FYI, here's the corresponding launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/330711.

Answer (score 2):

Some packages don't need to be rebuilt for different releases, e.g. documentation or python packages. Then choose "Copy existing binaries" option and the copy will succeed.

Comment: This works. There's no need to package with a different version number, as suggested by the other answer.