# Copying packages in PPA fail due to same version

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, launchpad

I copied my package from trusty's repository also to utopic's repository of my PPA *without re-building the binaries* by using Launchpad's copy packages feature. Now I noticed that the utopic package didn't work so I deleted it by using Launchpad's delete packages feature. Several hours later, my PPA now shows and publishes only for trusty so it seems to be ok. This time I copied the package using the *re-build binaries* option, but I get error "same version already has published binaries in the destination archive".

The question is: how can I REALLY REALLY REALLY delete the old packages from utopic's repository? I wouldn't like to release a new package version just because of this.

Comment: Ok...after some investigation it seems that this isn't even supposed to work / is bug in Launchpad and the error is misleading. http://askubuntu.com/questions/20835/how-do-i-copy-packages-within-a-ppa-from-one-release-to-another-nonsensical-s?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same repository (pool) for all series; and in any case you can never reuse a version for files with different content once it's been used in any given archive.  You must upload with a changed version number in order to get new builds.

Comment: Yeah, but it's still possible to copy packages using the same version without re-building. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/20835/how-do-i-copy-packages-within-a-ppa-from-one-release-to-another-nonsensical-s There's a comment that says: "It's a bug in launchpad that it either doesn't change the name/version or that it offers the option. "

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't offer the option to rebuild packages in that case.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/330711

Comment: Wow...filed in 2009 and still not fixed :)